# Setting up a maven-web project(from an existing netbeans-maven-web one)

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

So, I want to change a project here in my company to work with some IDE agnostic settings. I have a very small experience with setting Java applications with Tomcat(I can barely remember how it worked).

So, to help making our newest applications, independent from IDE's we are using Maven, which currently builds our spring applications nicely on both eclipse or Netbeans. But there are two  things I would like to know how to do with Maven:

Deploy the app to the test server.

Run the test server easily.

Both are tasks that Netbeans does automatically.

I would appreciate a lot, if anyone could give me detailed directions on how to do the thing.

Oh, for the moment we are using Tomcat as test server.

Comment: Do you mean from the command line? Also, is the test server local or remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the [Maven plugin for Tomcat](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/)
The link should tell you everything you want to know.

hth